# Delete ALL text to the left of a particular character in MS excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is an excel related question. I want to delete all text (all characters) to the left of a particular character or characters in the string.

**For instance:**

suppose I have an string in a cell
**helloall welco metostackoverflow**

now I want delete all the characters which are at the left side of "stack".
means result should be **stackoverflow** (only stackoverflow)

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Do you want to do it through VBA code?

Comment: This has been asked many times before. Please do not raise duplicate questions. Furthermore this is not a programming (VBA or VBscript question), so it would have been better asked at Super User

Comment: Seriously this question has 13k views and only one upvote?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
=RIGHT(input,LEN(input)-FIND("stack",input)+1)
```

Comment: @brettdj true, but easily fixed with: =IFERROR(RIGHT(input,LEN(input)-FIND("stack",input)+1),"")

Answer (score 0):

Another formula: 
=MID(input,20,60)

Here 1st numeric is 20 because "s" in "helloall welco metostackoverflow" is the 20th character from left considering each space also a character. 2nd numeric( 60 here) is any number greater than the numbers of characters in desired text "stackoverflow". In "stackoverflow" there are 13 characters. So in the given formula 2nd numeric can be any positive integer equal or greater than 13.

Answer (score 0):

do a find replace and use a wildcard.

e.g.

Find: *Stack
Replace: Stack

Result would be "Stack Overflow"