# Excel: Delete ALL to the right of the right of particular first "character"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to delete all text to the right of the first "|" in a group of cells.

I had been using this:

```
=IFERROR(RIGHT(input,LEN(input)-FIND("stack",input)+1),"")
```

to delete to the left of a specific character. I found this in [a stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472031/delete-all-text-to-the-left-of-a-particular-character-in-ms-excel).

I am not sure how to make it so it reads to find the FIRST specific character. I also am trying to delete to the right of, but I believe I can fix that myself.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `LEFT(input, FIND("|", input))` +/- 1 as needed..? or `MID(..)` to get some text from the middle..

Comment: Oh nice it just grabs the first 1 anyway, thanks this seems to be doing the trick

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by *the first "|" in a group of cells* you mean the leftmost pipe character in each cell of an array of cells then as @Aprillion suggests `=LEFT(A1,FIND("|",A1)-1)` seems a good approach (where A1 is the first element of the array and the formula is copied across/down as appropriate).

If the group is a column, an alternative could be to use Data > Data Tools – Text to Columns with Delimited and Other: `|`, then delete inserted columns as required.